# Not getting response from Gmail API (Users.messages: send) -- running on mobile device via IonicFramework + AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, email, ionic-framework, gmail-api

I am able to send emails successfully using [GMail's API](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/send) with no issues. The receiver gets the email after a few seconds, but the app doesn't get a response from GMail (i.e., threadid, id, etc...) described [here](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/uploads).

I'm running this on a mobile device via IonicFramework w/c uses angularJS by the way. What could be wrong?

```
$http({
  method: 'POST',
  url: 'https://www.googleapis.com/upload/gmail/v1/users/me/messages/send?uploadType=multipart',
  headers: {
    'Authorization':'Bearer '+ access_token,
    'Content-Type': 'multipart/mixed; boundary="foo_bar_baz"'
  },
  data: emailStr
})
.success(function(data, status, headers, config){
  console.log(data);            
})
.error(function(data, status, headers, config){
   console.log(data);                
});
```

emailStr contains the base64-encoded message.

This is how the request details look like:

```
Request URL: https://www.googleapis.com/upload/gmail/v1/users/me/messages/send?uploadType=multipart
Request Headers
Accept:application/json, text/plain, */*
Authorization:Bearer <<token here>>
Content-Type:multipart/mixed; boundary="foo_bar_baz"
Origin:file://
User-Agent: <<User agent data>>
Query String Parameters
uploadType:multipart
Request Payload
--foo_bar_baz
Content-Type: application/json; charset="UTF-8"

{"raw":"<<encoded string>>"}
--foo_bar_baz--
```

Comment: First place to check is your browser's *Network* console to see the requests being made and the responses returned.

Comment: I did check that but it's not getting a response. Eventually it just says failed.

Comment: Care to add some details then? Is the request timing out? What is the response status code / headers?

Comment: It ran for 2.1mins and didn't give out a reply. So I'm assuming it's timing out. I placed the request details on the problem so it's easier to see.

Comment: `Origin:file://` <- that's worrying. I'd recommend running the app over HTTP

Comment: Sorry I forgot, additional detail: I'm running this on a mobile device using ionic framework w/c uses angularJS.
Also, it actually is able to send the message. It's just that it doesn't get a reply from GMail

Comment: @Paul Are you trying to upload an attachment with the mail? Specifying uploadType=multipart in your 'url'-parameter will make Google wait for you to upload an attachment if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: yeah. so the attachment is in the second boundary. the weird thing is it worked tonight without changing anything. I'm not sure if it was just a glitch in the API.